# Checking the array size and list size inside a when statement in Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin

I am new to Kotlin and programming in general.
I really like the idea of pattern matching and as you can see at the code below, I was experimenting with the when statement.

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {


    val myAr = arrayOf(1,2,3)
    val myL = listOf(1,2,3)

    fun probablyBlind() {

       when(myL.size != myAr.size) {

          myL.size > myAr.size -> {
            println("myL.size > myAr.size = ${myL.size > myAr.size}")
          }
          myL.size < myAr.size -> myAr.forEach { println(it) }
      }

      if(myL.size != myAr.size) {
        println("Inside if. myL.size > myAr.size = 
        ${myL.size > myAr.size}")
      }
   }

   probablyBlind()
 }
```

If you run the code the result is :

```
myL.size > myAr.size = false
```

So that means that at some point the size of the list is different from the size of the array. 
Then it evaluates to true the first comparison inside the when statement.
But then it prints out false. Which means it shouldn't run this part of the code.
The if statement never evaluates to true.

Can anyone help me with this please?
Maybe it's something really easy that I can't see at the moment. 
If that's the case, excuse me.

Answer (score 12):

```
when(myL.size != myAr.size)
```

Here you specifed that the `when`-expression is a `Boolean` value, the result of comparing `MyL.size` and `myAr.size`. Let's say they are equal, this means you search for a match of the value `false`.

`myL.size > myAr.size` -- your first `when`-clause. Since the sizes are equal, this evaluates to `false` and matches the when-expression.

What you actually wanted to say was just

```
when {
    myL.size > myAr.size -> {
        println("myL.size > myAr.size = ${myL.size > myAr.size}")
      }
    myL.size < myAr.size -> myAr.forEach { println(it) }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The following is just a little showcase of another possibility, which might make sense in more complex scenarios.

You could wrap the comparison result into a few objects which let the `when` clause look nicely as follows:

```
fun probablyBlind() {
    when (ComparisonResult.of(myAr.size, myL.size)) {
        Equal -> {
            println("equally sized")
        }
        RightGreater -> println("myL.size > myAr.size = ${myL.size > myAr.size}")
        LeftGreater -> myAr.forEach { println(it) }
    }
}
```

To get it working simply create the following wrappers:

```
sealed class ComparisonResult {
    companion object {
        fun of(t1: Int, t2: Int): ComparisonResult = when {
            t1 == t2 -> Equal
            t1 > t2 -> LeftGreater
            t1 < t2 -> RightGreater
            else -> throw IllegalStateException()
        }
    }
}

object Equal : ComparisonResult()
object LeftGreater : ComparisonResult()
object RightGreater : ComparisonResult()
```